# Execute script in new terminal window on hard drive plugging

Tags: shell, terminal, ubuntu-16.04, xterm, udev

I would like to execute a backup script with rsync everytime a specific hard drive is plugged to my computer on ubuntu 16.04.
However I would like the user to be prompted if the backup should run or not and then he should be able to see the rsync output live in a terminal.

What I did so far:

- I created a rule at /etc/udev/rules.d/backup_on_mount.rules

  ```
  ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1058", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0820", RUN+="/path/to/my/script/backup_on_mount.sh"
  ```
- I created the backup_on_mount.sh script and made it executable

However I did not succeed in popping a new terminal window with my script running in it when I plug my hard drive.

Does anybody have an idea on how to begin ?

Thank you

Comment: Use `zenity` in your script.

Comment: What should happen if your hard drive is plugged in while no interactive user session exists?

Comment: ...to be clear, I'm staunchly in the this-is-a-bad-idea camp. Making your daemons aware of foreground interactive user sessions is actually liable if not likely to break in the future, if/as your OS vendor implements SELinux policy to keep processes out of things they shouldn't be in (and under normal circumstances, connecting to an X server from a udev-spawned process is definitely a thing that good security policy will prevent).

Comment: You're going to need to dig around to find the DISPLAY variable used by your current session, and the Xauthority file or other cookies used to authenticate to the X server. It's doable, but fragile and ugly; if all you want is to inform the user of start/completion/status, I'd suggest using [dbusnotify](http://software.clapper.org/dbusnotify/man/dbusnotify.1.html). Even then [some contortions will still be needed](http://www.hauweele.net/~gawen/blog/?p=834).

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, I actually want to execute the script ONLY IF I have an explicit confirmation by the current user.

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to run anything that long from `udev` rules directly. One way of dissociating your long running script from the `udev` rule is by *scheduling* it (with `at -M now` command for example) instead of running it directly. The proper way of finding the right `DISPLAY` to open the new terminal depends on your *desktop environment*